# Trying to plot a 3D curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to plot the curve `(exp(t)*cos(t), exp(t)*sin(t), exp(t)` by using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [view={60}{30}, axis lines=center,axis on top,
       xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
       xtick={10},ytick={10},ztick={10},
       no marks,axis equal,
       xmin=-1,xmax=10,ymin=-1,ymax=10,zmin=-1,zmax=10,
       enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
        \addplot3+[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0, domain=0:10, variable=\t]
     ( {(exp(\t))*cos(\t r)}, {(exp(\t))*sin(\t r)}, {exp(\t)} );
    \end{axis}
   \draw (1.6,1.7) node {$O$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the error is `!Dimension too large.`
Where do I wrong ?

Comment: this sounds like a bug. I will look into it https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/197/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, exp(10) is a rather large number. Why don't you just rescale all dimensions by exp(-5)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [view={60}{30}, axis lines=center,axis on top,
       xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
       xtick={10},ytick={10},ztick={10},
       no marks,axis equal,
       xmin=-1,xmax=10,ymin=-1,ymax=10,zmin=-1,zmax=10,
       enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
        \addplot3+[color=black, no markers,samples=1001, samples y=0,
        domain=0:10, variable=\t]
     ( {(exp(\t-5))*cos(\t r)}, {(exp(\t-5))*sin(\t r)}, {exp(\t-5)} );
    \end{axis}
   \draw (1.6,1.7) node {$O$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: e^5\approx 140... So not even plotted because of zmax=10... (Just mentioning because the selected numbers seems almost random to me) [But +1 for the answer]

Comment: @koleygr Sure. Thanks for the remark! The only point of my post is that one can solve the problem trivially by rescaling. Of course, if one is to plot the curve over the full range, one would have to rescale the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Yes... I agree that this is the best option in such problems... (This is the +1 for...)... I just had to mention this problem of the specific plot.